# Swift array not updating

Tags: json, swift

I can't get the retRecalls array updated. It's updating in the loop but the main one is empty and I can't find out why. If I print in the viewDidLoad is empty, if I print in the loop is ok.

```
var retRecalls = [Recalls]() ***** MAIN ARRAY

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    print(retRecalls) ***** EMPTY

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    Alamofire.request(recallsApi+vehicle).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response
        if let returnDict = result.value as? [String:Any] {
            if let recall = returnDict["recalls"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for i in recall {
                    let id = i["nnaId"]
                    let header = i["secondaryDescription"]
                    let summary = i["primaryDescription"]
                    let risk = i["riskIfNotRepaired"]
                    let remedy = i["remedyDescription"]
                    let recallsArray = Recalls(recallId: id as! String, header: header as! String, summary: summary as! String, risk: risk as! String , remedy: remedy as! String)
                    self.retRecalls.append(recallsArray)
                    print(retRecalls) **** IT'S UPDATING
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called before `viewWillAppear` and network calls are even slower to return than that.

Comment: And `viewDidLoad` is called before `viewDidAppear`, even if it weren't an async operation.

Comment: Wow! I was under the impression that viewWillAppear was called before viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to wait for your network call to return before the array is populated.

Putting `reloadData()` outside the network operation means it gets called right away. You want to defer this to being called once the network operation has completed, and your array has been populated.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    Alamofire.request(recallsApi+vehicle).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response
        if let returnDict = result.value as? [String:Any] {
            if let recall = returnDict["recalls"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for i in recall {
                    let id = i["nnaId"]
                    let header = i["secondaryDescription"]
                    let summary = i["primaryDescription"]
                    let risk = i["riskIfNotRepaired"]
                    let remedy = i["remedyDescription"]
                    let recallsArray = Recalls(recallId: id as! String, header: header as! String, summary: summary as! String, risk: risk as! String , remedy: remedy as! String)
                    self.retRecalls.append(recallsArray)
                    print(retRecalls) **** IT'S UPDATING
                }
            }
        }
        // Move the reloadData() call to here.
        dispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    // tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```